# Inaccessibility error : NUnit with console application

Tags: c#, console-application, nunit-2.5

I have written a console application in C# /VS2008. In that I have multiple classes declared without specifying any accessibility modifier. Like

```
Namespace MyNamespace
{
    Class MyClass
    {
    ..

    }
}
```

Now I added a new console application for testing purpose. I added reference to NUnit framework dll. And then a reference to my main project dll. But when I try to create an object of MyClass into my TestFixture class, then I get an error like "MyNamespace.MyClass is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Do I need to create my class as public? But what if my project cannot afford it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class needs to be [public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) if you want it to be accessible from another assembly:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {

    }
}
```

If your project cannot *afford it* you may take a look at [`[InternalsVisibleTo]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: Does it mean - If I cannot change it to public then I cannot test my application at all using NUnit?

Comment: Not only with NUnit but with any testing framework. You could always use reflection in your unit tests but this would be like shooting yourself in the legs. This of course doesn't mean that you cannot unit test your application. If this class is not public it means that the author didn't intend it to be accessible outside of the current assembly. You could always test the public methods that internally rely on this class and you will implicitly be testing it as well.

Comment: Then, can I have my test class in the main project itself? then will it be practicle to run the tests?

Comment: Yes, you can have your test class in your main project. I have even seen some people doing this. When you instruct NUnit to execute the tests it doesn't care whether the assembly is your main project or not: it simply looks for classes decorated with the [Test] attribute so this shouldn't be a problem. Whether this is good practice I prefer to remain silent and hear other people's opinion.